# Correct timezone for Django RSS syndication framework

Tags: django, timezone

I got the RSS feed setup on my django project by following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/)

But looks like the timestamp on the `<lastBuildDate>Thu, 23 Jan 2014 10:23:31 -0000</lastBuildDate>` is not giving the correct time offset, which should be +13 hours.

My settings are:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Pacific/Auckland'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-nz'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to define the item_pubdate function in the class:

```
from articles.models import Story
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
.
class LatestStoriesFeed(Feed):
    title = 'Latest stories'
    link = "/" 

    def items(self):
        return Story.active_objects.filter(sites__in=[current_site])[:10]
....
    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_descrpition(self, item):
        return item.introtext

    def item_link(self, item):
        return item.get_absolute_url()

    def item_pubdate(self, item):
        return item.publish_date
```